# f1_score metric in lightgbm

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm

I want to train a lgb model with custom metric : `f1_score` with `weighted` average.

I went through the advanced examples of lightgbm over [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/examples/python-guide/advanced_example.py) and found the implementation of custom binary error function. I implemented as similar function to return f1_score as shown below.

```
def f1_metric(preds, train_data):
    
    labels = train_data.get_label()
    
    return 'f1', f1_score(labels, preds, average='weighted'), True
```

I tried to train the model by passing `feval` parameter as `f1_metric` as shown below.

```
evals_results = {}

bst = lgb.train(params, 
                     dtrain, 
                     valid_sets= [dvalid], 
                     valid_names=['valid'], 
                     evals_result=evals_results, 
                     num_boost_round=num_boost_round,
                     early_stopping_rounds=early_stopping_rounds,
                     verbose_eval=25, 
                     feval=f1_metric)
```

Then I am getting `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples:`

The training set is being passed to the function rather than the validation set.

How can I configure such that the validation set is passed and f1_score is returned?

Comment: Which function actually complains? In a sense, is it `f1_score` that throws the error?

Comment: f1_score function throws the error

Comment: did you try to print out shapes of `preds`, `train_data`, `labels` inside of `f1_metric`?

Comment: Yeah, i did. That's how I came to know that the training set is passed to the function rather than the validation set

Comment: and what did you get?

Comment: I dont have the exact numbers with me. length of variable `labels` was larger than the length of variable `preds`

Comment: without a reproducible example I do not see how to debug it further. For sure custom objective functions in lighgbm do work, as I used them myself (I assume you are using a reasonably up-to-date version and it is not due to ancient artifact in the code).

Comment: I am using the latest version. I upgraded in using `conda`. It will he helpful if you could show a snippet in which you use custom metric to validate.

Comment: I failed to find where di i use it, but i remember that i followed the example from the central github repository: https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/blob/6488f319f243f7ff679a8e388a33e758c5802303/examples/python-guide/advanced_example.py#L135-L143

Comment: Thank you. I believe I used the same source to get started with. I will cross check and keep you posted

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The docs are a bit confusing. When describing the signature of the function that you pass to feval, they call its parameters *preds* and *train_data*, which is a bit misleading.

But the following seems to work:

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

def lgb_f1_score(y_hat, data):
    y_true = data.get_label()
    y_hat = np.round(y_hat) # scikits f1 doesn't like probabilities
    return 'f1', f1_score(y_true, y_hat), True

evals_result = {}

clf = lgb.train(param, train_data, valid_sets=[val_data, train_data], valid_names=['val', 'train'], feval=lgb_f1_score, evals_result=evals_result)

lgb.plot_metric(evals_result, metric='f1')
```

To use more than one custom metric, define one overall custom metrics function just like above, in which you calculate all metrics and return a list of tuples.

Edit: Fixed code, of course with F1 bigger is better should be set to True.

Comment: I will try running this and keep you posted

Comment: I am getting an error and `f1_score` is not calculated. Error is `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning:

F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no predicted samples.`

Comment: That is not an error, it is a warning. Check your predictions to make sure they are not all zero. Also, above works for binary classification. If you have more than two classes, you need to modify it. If the answer was helpful, please consider upoting or accepting.

Comment: If all the predictions are 0 then why does it throw such a warning.? It can calculate it accordingly and give a low f1_score as output

Comment: That's exactly what it does, it sets the score to 0.0 and warns you, because it is likely that there is a bug somewhere when all your predictions are zero.

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Toby! Will this still work as is with 'is_unbalance' set to True, or will I need calibration?

Answer (score 11):

Regarding Toby's answers:

```
def lgb_f1_score(y_hat, data):
    y_true = data.get_label()
    y_hat = np.round(y_hat) # scikits f1 doesn't like probabilities
    return 'f1', f1_score(y_true, y_hat), True
```

I suggest change the  y_hat part to this:

```
y_hat = np.where(y_hat < 0.5, 0, 1)
```

Reason:
I used the y_hat = np.round(y_hat) and fonud out that during training the lightgbm model will sometimes(very unlikely but still a change) regard our y prediction to multiclass instead of binary.

My speculation:
Sometimes the y prediction will be small or higher enough to be round to negative value or 2?I'm not sure,but when i changed the code using np.where, the bug is gone.

Cost me a morning to figure this bug,although I'm not really sure if the np.where solution is good.

Comment: I'm not really sure what does "provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker" mean, after seeing the link you gave. Well, I'll edit comment on the answers that I found i can improve upon then.