# Custom metric function with LightGBM cross validation

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, lightgbm

So since lightGBM doesnt have a f1 score i'm trying to make use of a custom eval function but it isnt working.

I've tried basing myself from [f1_score metric in lightgbm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931168/f1-score-metric-in-lightgbm) and https://www.kaggle.com/code/mlisovyi/lighgbm-hyperoptimisation-with-f1-macro and came up with this reproducible example:

```
import lightgbm as lgb
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
import warnings
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
import pandas as pd

# Suppress Python warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Create a dummy DataFrame for training and validation
train = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': np.arange(100),
    'feature1': np.random.rand(100),
    'feature2': np.random.rand(100),
    'label': np.random.randint(2, size=100)
})

# Prepare the training data
X = train.drop(["id", "label"], axis=1)
y = train["label"]
train_data = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)

# Define the hyperparameter grid
def evaluate_macroF1_lgb(truth, predictions):  
    # this follows the discussion in https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1483
    pred_labels = predictions.reshape(len(np.unique(truth)),-1).argmax(axis=0)
    f1 = f1_score(truth, pred_labels, average='macro')
    return ('macroF1', f1, True) 

param_grid = {
    'objective': ['binary'],
    'metric': [['auc', 'binary_error', evaluate_macroF1_lgb]],
    'min_data_in_leaf': [20, 50],
    'verbose': [-1],
    'is_unbalance': [True], # Option 2
    # 'feval': [evaluate_macroF1_lgb], Doesnt work
}

# Perform cross-validation with 5 folds for each combination of hyperparameters
best_error = float('inf')
best_params = {}
max_length_param_grid = len(list(product(*param_grid.values())))
for params_combination in tqdm(product(*param_grid.values()), total=max_length_param_grid):
    params = dict(zip(param_grid.keys(), params_combination))
    cv_results = lgb.cv(params, train_data, num_boost_round=100, nfold=5, stratified=True, verbose_eval=False)
    mean_error = np.mean(cv_results['auc-mean'])
    if mean_error < best_error:
        best_error = mean_error
        best_params = params
        
cv_results.keys()
```

That outputs just `dict_keys(['auc-mean', 'auc-stdv', 'binary_error-mean', 'binary_error-stdv'])`

Is ignoring my custom macroF1 function to evaluate F1, any way to make lgt.cv also compute that metric?

Comment: In the future, please follow the advice in "How to create a minimal, reproducible example" ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), especially focusing on "minimal". The grid search code, filtering Python warnings, and some other details in this example weren't necessary to reproduce the issue you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `cv()` function from `lightgbm` (the Python package for LightGBM), custom eval functions...

- ... should be passed to keyword argument `feval`, not via the `params` dictionary
- ... must follow the signature `eval(preds: np.ndarray, dataset: lightgbm.Dataset) -> Tuple[str, float, bool]`

  - as documented at https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.cv.html

Here's a minimal example using `lightgbm==4.0.0`:

```py
import lightgbm as lgb
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)
dtrain = lgb.Dataset(X, label=y)


def f1_metric(preds, eval_dataset):
    metric_name = "f1"
    y_true = eval_dataset.get_label()
    value = f1_score(y_true, preds > 0.5)
    higher_better = True
    return metric_name, value, higher_better


cv_results = lgb.cv(
    params={
        "objective": "binary",
        "metric": ["auc", "binary_error"],
        "verbose": -1,
        "is_unbalance": True
    },
    num_boost_round=3,
    train_set=dtrain,
    feval=f1_metric
)

print(cv_results)
```

```
{
    'valid auc-mean': [0.969416022404886, 0.9758411039016182, 0.9790091106501195],
    'valid auc-stdv': [0.013865471872931289, 0.014781297162168049, 0.016711513735684278],
    'valid binary_error-mean': [0.3725818972209284, 0.3725818972209284, 0.09316876261450086],
    'valid binary_error-stdv': [0.003948679172659218, 0.003948679172659218, 0.030261598480681225],
    'valid f1-mean': [0.7710522724688222, 0.7710522724688222, 0.930904989872778],
    'valid f1-stdv': [0.002983063497564946, 0.002983063497564946, 0.020544626363969858]
}
```